# Simplificar código javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, revisión-de-código

Me gustaría que me ayudasen a simplificar este código con algún tipo de *class*. La verdad es que no conozco tanto como para hacerlo yo mismo. Les dejo un ejemplo de otra simpflicación con la que amablemente me han ayudado en este foro que es la función de la clase intime.

Este es el código que quiero simplificar:

```js
var kk = false;
var t = false;
var XX = false;
var ff = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / DocHeight;
  if (scrollPercent >= 5 && variableXX == false) {
    variableXX = true;
    $(".onscroll5").fadeIn(0);
  } else if (scrollPercent < 5 && variableXX == true) {
    variableXX = false;
    $(".onscroll5").fadeIn(0);
  }
  if (scrollPercent >= 10 && t == false) {
    t = true;
    $(".onscroll10").fadeIn(0);
  } else if (scrollPercent < 10 && t == true) {
    t = false;
    $(".onscroll10").fadeIn(0);
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / DocHeight;
  if (scrollPercent >= 20 && kk == false) {
    kk = true;
    $(".outscroll20").fadeOut(0);
  } else if (scrollPercent < 20 && kk == true) {
    kk = false;
    $(".outscroll20").fadeOut(0);
  }
  if (scrollPercent >= 25 && ff == false) {
    ff = true;
    $(".outscroll25").fadeOut(0);
  } else if (scrollPercent < 25 && ff == true) {
    ff = false;
    $(".outscroll25").fadeOut(0);
  }
});
```

Y para ello quería basarme en este ejemplo:

```
$(function() {
  // para todos los elementos que contengan intime en su clase
  $("[class*=intime]").each(function() {
    // usar expresiones regulares para obtener el número detras de intime
    var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/intime\d+/g)[0].replace("intime", ""));
    // mostrar el elemento con el retraso adecuado
    $(this).delay(retraso * 1000).fadeIn(0);
  });
});
```

Lo estoy intentando por mi cuenta y hasta ahora he hecho esto, y aunque no funciona, creo que los tiros podrían ir por aquí:

```
var variableXX = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / DocHeight;
  var porcentaje = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/inscroll\d+/g)[0].replace("onscroll",""));
  if (scrollPercent >= porcentaje && variableXX == false) {
    variableXX = true;
    $("[class*=onscroll]").fadeIn(0);
  } else if (scrollPercent < porcentaje && variableXX == true) {
    variableXX = false;
    $(".onscroll5").fadeIn(0);
  }
});
```

Comment: Debes agregar que es lo que se supone que haga el código para que la pregunta tenga un poco más de claridad.

Comment: El código introduce un elemento etiquetado con una clase y lo hace desaparecer a los porcentajes de scroll dados @devconcept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es hacerlo genérico para que funcione no sólo con 5, 10, 20 y 25 sino también con cualquier otro valor, como en el ejemplo que pones (y que yo mismo compartí en otra pregunta :P), la cosa se va a complicar bastante más.

Estas funciones son más específicas que las de los casos anteriores. Antes sólo dependían del número que aparecía en la clase, ahora también dependen de una variable que cambia de una clase a otra (`XX`, `t`, `kk` y `ff` para `onscroll5`, `onscroll10`, `onscroll20` y `onscroll25` respectivamente).

Y además, para algunas clases se hace `fadeIn` y para otras `fadeOut`, sin haber relación aparente entre la clase y la función que debe ejecutarse en cada caso. Lo que te obligará a crear una estructura para guardar todas las variables (clase, porcentaje, variable y función; aunque el porcentaje se puede obtener a partir de la clase) y casi crearía más complejidad de la que hay.

---

Una vez dicho esto, sí que podrías intentar reducir el código combinando las funciones (los controladores del scroll) y los `if`s (si te fijas son el mismo código en el `if` y el `else if`) para que todo sea más corto y fácil de leer:

```
var kk = false;
var t  = false;
var XX = false;
var ff = false;

// un único controlador del evento scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {

  // una única variable scrollPercent
  var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / DocHeight;

  // combina las dos condiciones en una sola porque las dos hacen lo mismo
  if ((scrollPercent >= 5 && XX == false) || (scrollPercent < 5 && XX == true) {
    XX = !XX;                  // cambia el valor de la variable
    $(".onscroll5").fadeIn(0); // esconde el elemento
  }

  if ((scrollPercent >= 10 && t == false) || (scrollPercent < 10 && t == true)) {
    t = !t;
    $(".onscroll10").fadeIn(0);
  }

  if ((scrollPercent >= 20 && kk == false) || (scrollPercent < 20 && kk == true)) {
    kk = !kk;
    $(".outscroll20").fadeOut(0);
  }

  if ((scrollPercent >= 25 && ff == false) || (scrollPercent < 25 && ff == true)) {
    ff = !ff;
    $(".outscroll25").fadeOut(0);
  }

});
```

Se podría hacer más corto incluso cambiando cosas como `variable == false` por `!variable`, o `variable == true` simplemente por `variable`. Y quizás se pudiese reducir más la condición.

Comment: Bueno muchas gracias @alvaromontoro a veces uno intenta hacer cosas demasiado complejas ! jeje